# eBay API OutOfStockControlPreference with quantity 0 returns 'Quantity is not valid'

Tags: ebay-api

Following the [instructions for OutOfStockControlPreference](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/guides/ebayfeatures/Development/Listings-UseOutOfStock.html), I've set it to true, and even verified using `ShowOutOfStockControlPreference`.

Next, my call is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReviseInventoryStatusRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>-- removed --</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <InventoryStatus>
        <ItemID>**********</ItemID>
        <Quantity>0</Quantity>
    </InventoryStatus>
</ReviseInventoryStatusRequest>
```

eBay returns a 515 error:

```
Array(
    [ReviseInventoryStatusResponse] => Array(
            [Timestamp] => 2014-10-28T16:05:19.176Z
            [Ack] => Failure
            [Errors] => Array(
                [ShortMessage] => Quantity is not valid.
                [LongMessage] => The quantity must be a valid number greater than 0.
                [ErrorCode] => 515
                [SeverityCode] => Error
                [ErrorParameters] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                                [Value] => **********
                            )
                        [1] => Array(
                                [Value] => Array(
                                    )
                            )
                    )
                [ErrorClassification] => RequestError
            )
        [Version] => 891
        [Build] => E891_UNI_API5_17051033_R1
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [unsupported in the eBay sandbox](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=684), but it works for eBay live.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm genuinely curious why it's so hard to replicate all functionality in the sandbox. Seems like it's just two environments running the same application, shouldn't be too hard. Alas, it is.